# Bayes Theorem and conditional repetition of events? Like getting a false postive twice / $n$ times?

Tags: definition, bayes-theorem

A while ago I learned about the [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). Among many other things, it allows to compute a probability for some healthy person to get a (false) positive drug test result -i.e. a probability of some event like "getting a positive drug test result" - let's call it $A$ - happening given that some other (independent) event like "being a healthy person" - $B$ - has already happened; within a standard notation it would translate to the $P(A|B)$.

I am trying to make a next obvious step. What is a probability for a healthy person to get a positive drug test result **twice**? In other words: what is a probability for a false positive to repeat again? It seems that there are two different ways I could approach the problem:

1. $A_1$ would mean that the person got a positive drug test result at the first iteration. $A_2$ would stand for the second one. In that case I could ask $P(A_1 \cap A_2 | B)$ where $A_1 \cap A_2$ means "event $A_1$ and $A_2$ are both happened". To my understanding, this formulation implies seeing $A_1$ and $A_2$ as **independent of each other** - and it is crucial. It seems to be not quite what I am initially was looking for; a more right way to ask the question would be:
2. $P(A_2 | (A_1 | B))$ - what is a probability for $A_2$ to happen given that $A_1$ **assumed to happen** under $B$. Expanding $A_1$, $A_2$ and $B$ to their original meanings, it asks the following question: "what is a probability for a healthy person ($B$) to get a second false positive drug test result ($A_2$) assuming he or she already got one ($A_1$)?". It seems to be exactly the right way to define the problem. Also, as a side note, it does state **an implicit dependency** between two false positives ($A_1$, $A_2$) over the $B$.

What I am looking for is confirmation whether my way of thinking is correct or explanation why not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't make  decisions  about yourself or a loved one  based on trying to understand applied statistics.

Comment: @WillJagy it isn't about that, the example I've taken is entirely artificial, just a simple illustration. most of the textbooks on the subject would introduce a false positive drug test puzzle anyways.

Comment: Medical Statistics is complicated.  Here, one would need to know the extent (if any) to which trial errors are independent.  Perhaps a false positive is (or might be) reflective of a different condition in which case, those with the other condition might be expected to constantly get false positives.  Without specific study, who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positive/negative test result given a healthy/sick patient is a classic example used when introducing Bayes. Another popular one is the probability of defective products in a batch. As always with these examples, you have to make simplifying assumptions, that don't always correspond to reality.

In your case, the mathematically correct approach is the first one. As others have noted, the second formulation is ill-posed. Now, whether or not you simplify your problem as expressed in your first formulation by assuming conditional independence is entirely up to you, and will ultimately determine the predictive power of your model.

It seems that you are interested in the probability of the first and second tests both being positive given that the patient is actually healthy. So what you are asking for is $P(T_1 \cap T_2|H)$. You could assume that $T_1 $ and $T_2$ are independent given H and therefore the above becomes $P(T_1|H)P(T_2|H)$. But as you pointed out, this might not correspond to your intuition about the problem.

Hence, you would have to look for other ways to **model** this distribution. You would collect empirical data and try to fit the joint data-generating distribution. This is starting to enter the realms of mathematical modelling and statistical learning.

Note that you can still apply Bayes theorem without the conditional independence assumption. It would look like:

$$ P(T_1 \cap T_2 | H) = \frac{P(H|T_1 \cap T_2)P(T_1 \cap T_2)}{P(H)} $$

Depending on whether you have information about this likelihood and prior, this could still be useful.